# it is good and safe to use debian software raid?

Tags: debian, raid, software-raid, debian-squeeze

My questions is as simple as the title: `it is good and safe to use debian6  software raid?`
How safe it is?
Can i have a software RAID configuration backup?
How can i deal/recover with/from a HDD problem?

I've been reading a lot over the internet, but everyone is talking 'bout how to configure.  I already managed to configure and install a Debian squeeze software RAID, but, will the grub boot loader be installed in both disk, or should i do that manually??

Thanks

Comment: This depends also on the RAID level used - as a rule of thumb: RAID1 is reliable but storage-hungry, RAID5 is problematic, RAID6 has both advantages and drawbacks. Don't even think about RAID0. RAID10 is an option, but not something I'd recommend for a beginner (pardon my assumption). See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

Linux (and Debian) software RAID is arguably more reliable than hardware RAID.

You can back up /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

Read [mdadm(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) documentation.

I can't remember if squeeze will automatically install grub on both disks, but you can verify and do it easily enough your self afterwards. Just `grub-install /dev/sd?`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if i backup the `mdadm.conf`, in the future i can change a damaged disk, put another, restore the file, and everything is ok again?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restore the file. I've replaced disks without doing that. But backing it up can provide some extra security in case something fails spectacularly.